# Forward declaration inside a namespace

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I've encountered a strange problem when trying to compile my code in Visual Studio (2010); here's an isolated (and simplified) example:

```
class A
{
public:
  enum {
    VALUE   = 0
  };
};

namespace ns
{

class A;

class B
{
public:
  B(int val = ::A::VALUE) // this line
  {}
};

class A : public ::A
{
public:
};

}
```

This gives the following error: `error C2027: use of undefined type 'ns::A'`. Is it a bug in VS or am I doing something wrong?

**Update:** this appears to be a bug specific to Visual Studio. Here's a workaround suggested on Microsoft Connect:

```
class B
{
public:
  typedef ::A A1;
  B(int val = A1::VALUE)
  {}
};
```

Comment: Which line is triggering the error?

Comment: Should I make the comment more visible?

Comment: Ah sorry, I looked for it but must have overlooked it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in VC10. Your `::A` class name is fully qualified, and the definition of `A` in the global namespace is visible to the compiler. Besides, GCC 4.7.2 compiles this without problems.

Comment: Thanks, I already tried it in an online gcc tester; does anyone know if it works with VC12?

Comment: @riv: Can't test on VC12 unfortunately

Comment: @riv, I just tried to compile your snippet above with VC12 and I get similar errors.